# Перенос дочерних элементов в контейнере flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Прошу помочь с задачей.
Пытаюсь построить ряд из квадратиков на flexbox, по аналогии как это делается с сеткой товаров в интернет магазинах.
Нужно, чтобы все квадраты были расположены по центру (это получилось) но при сужении экрана тот квадрат которые переносится должен вставать четко под квадрат № 1, т.е. сначала строки а не по центру.

Нагуглил решение, но оно на основе добавления фейковых элементов, всё работает, но как эти элементы убрать или скрыть, чтобы снизу не образовывался большой отступ?
Вот сам исходник

```css
.parent {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #FFD54F;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent .item,
.parent .dummyItem {
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background: #c7ffc4;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent .dummyItem {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Убрать у них все выступающие части. В частности border и margin

Comment: @AlexeyTen, без маргинов и бордеров будет вот так (следите при изменении размеров экрана за блоками 7 и 8): https://jsfiddle.net/k4munoft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обнулить вертикальную составляющую у `dummyItem`.

```css
.parent {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #FFD54F;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent .item,
.parent .dummyItem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #c7ffc4;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent .dummyItem {
  height: 0px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 11px; /* 11px что бы скомпенсировать удалённый border. */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
  <div class="dummyItem"></div>
</div>
```